# Multiway using priority queue

Tags: java, algorithm, merge, priority-queue

This is an example in Sedgewick; Wayne: *Algorithms* 4th edition. But I can't figure it out. Please Help!

Here is the code:

```
package algorithm2_4;

import chap1.*;

public class Multiway {
private Multiway() {
}

private static void merge(In[] streams) {
    int n = streams.length;
    IndexMinPQ<String> pq = new IndexMinPQ<String>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (!streams[i].isEmpty())
            pq.insert(i, streams[i].readString());
    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        StdOut.print(pq.minKey() + " ");
        int i = pq.delMin();
        if (!streams[i].isEmpty())
            pq.insert(i, streams[i].readString());
    }
    StdOut.println();
}

/**
 * Reads sorted text files specified as command-line arguments; merges them
 * together into a sorted output; and writes the results to standard output.
 * Note: this client does not check that the input files are sorted.
 *
 * @param args
 *            the command-line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = args.length;
    In[] streams = new In[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        streams[i] = new In(args[i]);
    merge(streams);
}
}
```

if
%more m1.txt
A C D E
%more m2.txt
B S Z
then
%java Multiway m1.txt m2.txt
A B C D E S Z

By the way, `IndexMinPQ` is a heap-based implementation of the [`IndexMinPQ` API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nx9D.jpg) below.
I don't quite understand why the code above can merge several sorted lists to one.
Can someone explain it to me?

> `class IndexMinPQ<Item extends Comparable<Item>>`
>
> ---
>
> `IndexMinPQ(int maxN)`     *create a priority queue of capacity* `maxN`
>                                     *with possible indices between* `0` *and* `maxN-1`
>       `void insert(int k, Item item)` *insert* `item`*; associate it with* `k`
>       `void change(int k, Item item)` *change the item associated with* `k` *to* `item`
>    `boolean contains(int k)`          *is* `k` *associated with some item?*
>       `void delete(int k)`            *remove* `k` *and its associated item*
>       `Item min()`                    *return a minimal item*
>        `int minIndex()`               *return a minimal item's index*
>        `int delMin()`                 *remove a minimal item and return its index*
>    `boolean isEmpty()`                *is the priority queue empty?*
>        `int size()`                   *number of items in the priority queue*

Comment: Forgot to say. IndexMinPQ is a heap-based implementation of this API.

Comment: `Forgot to say` please edit your question instead of commenting on any deficiencies. The title seems to be lacking one word. (Is that `%more…` *followed by* `%java…`? Then, it should read *then* rather than `than`.)

Comment: (The "magic" seems to be in `class IndexMinPQ<>`.)

Comment: @greybeard Sorry for typing the wrong word...First time to ask a question here so I'm a little rattled.I have submitted the API of IndexMinPQ.

Comment: `Sorry for typing the wrong word` Never feel sorry for making mistakes - not making mistakes means not getting things done. Save that for *not trying to avoid mistakes*, *not learning from mistakes*, and *not caring about adverse effects, especially for others*. `[my first] time to ask a question here so I'm a little rattled` [no need to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Just try to heed [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [answer], and [ask].

Comment: Which part of the code don't you understand? Code is something you read line by line and try to understand like that, so there's presumably a specific part you don't understand. It won't really make sense to explain the code line-by-line if you already understand basically all of it, nor would it really make sense to explain the code line-by-line if you understand *none* of it (because such an explanation would be too long and you should probably just read a programming textbook).

Comment: I have known the thinking of this code. Thanks!